# How to proxy a media stream in Node?

Tags: node.js, proxy, stream, audio-streaming, icecast

I want to be able to proxy a remote icecast stream to client. I've been fiddling around a lot in the past few days to no avail.

**Use case**:

Be able to extract analyser data out of an `<audio>` tag `src` without running into CORS issues.

**My solution so far**

In order to address CORS issues preventing me to create an leverage sound data directly out of the `<audio>`'s source, I've tried to write a tiny proxy which would pipe requests to a specific stream and return statics in any other case.
Here is my code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const http = require('http');

const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

let target = 'http://direct.fipradio.fr/live/fip-midfi.mp3';
// figure out 'real' target if the server returns a 302 (redirect)
http.get(target, resp => {
  if(resp.statusCode == 302) {
    target = resp.headers.location;
  }
});

app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  http.get(target, audioFile => {
    res.set(audioFile.headers);

    audioFile.addListener('data', (chunk) => {
      res.write(chunk);
    });
    audioFile.addListener('end', () => {
      res.end();
    });
  }).on('error', err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
});

app.listen(PORT);
```

**The problem**

The client receives a response from the proxy but this gets stalled to 60kb of data about and subsequent chunks are not received, in spite of being received by the proxy:

[image]

[image]

Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: HTTP proxying is actually quite complex.  I recommend simply using Nginx or similar.  If you need to do this in Node.js, there are NPM packages for proxying.  At the very least, you can pipe your upstream response directly to the client response... they're streams.  What you're doing now has no flow control, and also doesn't properly handle errors.

Answer (score 4):

I've found a solution, use stream pipe.

```
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

let target = 'http://direct.fipradio.fr/live/fip-midfi.mp3';
// figure out 'real' target if the server returns a 302 (redirect)
http.get(target, resp => {
  if(resp.statusCode == 302) {
    target = resp.headers.location;
  }
});

app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  req.pipe(request.get(target)).pipe(res);
});

app.listen(PORT);
```

Comment: What about if I would like to do some processing on audio before streaming it forward? Do you maybe have a solution for that pupose?

Comment: yes we can also achieve that with simple tweaking, as we are using the pipes we can join 2 or more pipe.
Example: Suppose, if we want to compress the target contents before sending back we can modify our pipe code like below .


`var zlib = require('zlib');`
`var gzip = zlib.createGzip();`

`req.pipe(request.get(target)).pipe(gzip).pipe(res);`

Comment: If you need more control for proxying you can try this [NPM Module - Mississippi](https://github.com/maxogden/mississippi)